# How to check matching array values in php?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop, foreach

Hi i have a repeating dates in array values i wan to count the number of repeating dates from the array value. I tried this but am not sure to do it correctly and am getting error `Undefined offset: 0`

```
<?php $array = array('2013-11-28','2013-11-28','2013-11-28','2013-11-29','2013-11-29','2013-11-30');

$len = sizeof($array);
$len = $len-1;
$day = array();
for($i=0; $i<=$len; $i++)
{
    for($j=0; $j<=$len; $j++)
    {
        if($array[$i] == $array[$j])
        {
            if($day[0] == '')
            {
                $co = 1;
                $day[] = $co;
            }
            else {
                $day[$i] = $co++;
            }
        }
    }
    echo 'day'.$i.' '.$day[$i].' ';
}
?>
```

From the date values i should get 3 for 2013-11-28, 2 for 2013-11-29 and 1 for 2013-11-30 as you can see 2013-11-28 is presented 3 times , 2013-11-29 is presented 2 times and 
2013-11-30 is presented one time.

I can understand that i am wrongly calculating because in the second loop i am again starting from first index so increasing the count.

I want to know the count of same dates. How to do this. Any other way to count this? Any help please?

Comment: You want to group and count? like `2013-11-28 = 3`, `2013-11-29 = 2` and `2013-11-30 = 1`?

Comment: $len = sizeof($array); use $len = count($array);

Comment: @SHIN `sizeof` and `count` are equivalent.

Comment: The error is because of `if ($day[0] == '')`. You do this before you ever add anything to `$day`, so there's no element 0 yet.

Comment: yes, thanks. +1 for sizeof and count @Barmar

Comment: @Barmar sizeof and count are not equivalent, sizeof is an alias of count.. if you use `sizeof()` it will call `count()` in actual

Comment: Yes i want to group and count @haim770

Comment: @zzlalani That means it returns the same value as `count`, so they're semantically equivalent.

Comment: Why minus vote for me. I tried by my own even am wrong. From here i'll learn and correct the wrong things.

Comment: @Barmar `equivalent` means two different things equal to each other

Comment: @zzlalani `count($array) === sizeof($array)` is always true, isn't it?

Comment: @Barmar yes because you are calling to the same function.. not different functions are returning same values of same type

Comment: @zzlalani I don't understand our argument. If they're calling the same function, then they're equivalent. Maybe there's a slight performance difference because of an extra function call.

Comment: yes have a look at this to understand what I'm arguing for. http://us2.php.net/sizeof. i dont want your comment left an impression that they both are different functions doing same thing.. this is just a nonsense of php..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php).

```
$dupesCount = array_count_values($array);
```

This will give you an array where the value is the key and the new value is the repetition count.

Comment: Thanks for easy answer. Can that be done in my loop logic too? @alex

Comment: @sun You wouldn't need to loop yourself.